# how to update column A dynamically by other columns based on cell values of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We need to update a column A , by either column B or column C or column D . Which column is to be used will be decided by column X which contains the cell values as "column B" or "column C" or "column D"

This is required in pyspark dataframes

Comment: Please provide example of input data set and desired output. Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) to achieve this.

Variable `possible_values` inside `derive_column_A()` controls all the possible column values. From this we dynamically construct a condition to choose appropriate column.

## Example

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("B1", "C1", "D1", "column C"),
        ("B2", "C2", "D2", "column D"), 
        ("B3", "C3", "D3", "column B"), 
        ("B4", "C4", "D4", "column D")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("B", "C", "D", "X"))

def derive_column_A():
    possible_values = ["column B", "column C", "column D"]
    column_mapping = [{col, col.split(" ")[1]} for col in possible_values]
    condition = F
    for possible_value in possible_values:
        condition = condition.when(F.col("X") == possible_value, F.col(possible_value.split(" ")[1]))
    return condition


df.withColumn("A", derive_column_A()).show()
```

### Output

```
+---+---+---+--------+---+
|  B|  C|  D|       X|  A|
+---+---+---+--------+---+
| B1| C1| D1|column C| C1|
| B2| C2| D2|column D| D2|
| B3| C3| D3|column B| B3|
| B4| C4| D4|column D| D4|
+---+---+---+--------+---+
```